# Modify writability/readability of existing properties of JS objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wondering if there is a way to modify existing properties of objects in JS so that we can make them immutable after assignment.

Basically, I have an object, I would like to freeze the existing properties on the object, but allow new properties to be added.

Is it possible to freeze existing properties, or do I need to use Object.defineProperty like so:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

I doubt it's possible to modify permissions on properties after the fact, but I wonder if there is some secret trick to use.

I believe Object.freeze will be overkill because I want to allow new properties to be added later.

As you can see, it appears you can't add properties after an object is "frozen"

```js
var z = Object.freeze({
    a: 'c'
});

z.b = 'm';

console.log(z);
```

The motivation for this is that I am writing a library, and want to prevent / (throw an error), if a developer using the library overwrites existing properties belonging to the library.

On this topic, wth is the difference between Object.freeze and Object.seal?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806192(v=vs.94).aspx

As soon as I saw Object.seal, I was like oh! this must be what I am looking for, nope, seems identical to Object.freeze, lame.

Comment: did you have a look at https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ ?

Comment: yeah, Immutable will probably work, but you have to create Immutable objects first, not modify the properties after the fact. The problem with Immutable is that I need to do some prototypical inheritance and freeze the prototype as well.

Answer (score 1):

What about to use Object.defineProperty() and set permisson for all existing attributes?

For example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Luo80szt/

```
var myCar = new Object();
myCar.make = "Ford";
myCar.model = "Mustang";

Object.defineProperty(myCar, "make", { writable : false });

myCar.make ="BMW";
myCar.model ="Ranchero";
myCar.color  ="white";


for(var key in myCar) {
    console.log(myCar[key]);
}
```

I just used for one attribute but you can iterate through all object properties

Comment: ah, so you don't have to re-assign the values? just modify them?

Comment: after  "writable : false" assginment, attribute will be not modifiable but you can continue  to add new one.

Comment: huh, this seems to work, will experiment with it to verify